# Referencing nested groups in JavaScript using string replace using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-group

Because of the way that jQuery deals with script tags, I've found it necessary to do some HTML manipulation using regular expressions (yes, I know... not the ideal tool for the job).  Unfortunately, it seems like my understanding of how captured groups work in JavaScript is flawed, because when I try this:

```
var scriptTagFormat = /<script .*?(src="(.*?)")?.*?>(.*?)<\/script>/ig;

html = html.replace(
    scriptTagFormat, 
    '<span class="script-placeholder" style="display:none;" title="$2">$3</span>');
```

The script tags get replaced with the spans, but the resulting `title` attribute is blank.  Shouldn't `$2` match the content of the `src` attribute of a script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that regular expressions by themselves can't do exactly what I'm looking for, so here's my modification to work around the problem:

```
var scriptTagFormat = /<script\s+((.*?)="(.*?)")*\s*>(.*?)<\/script>/ig;

html = html.replace(
    scriptTagFormat, 
    '<span class="script-placeholder" style="display:none;" $1>$4</span>');
```

Before, I wanted to avoid setting non-standard attributes on the replacement `span`.  This code blindly copies all attributes instead.  Luckily, the non-standard attributes aren't stripped out of the DOM when I insert the HTML, so it will work for my purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Nesting of groups is irrelevant; their numbering is determined strictly by the positions of their opening parentheses within the regex.  In your case, that means it's group #1 that captures the whole `src="value"` sequence, and group #2 that captures just the `value` part.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*?` matches too much because the following group is optional, ==> your `src` is matched from one of the `.*?` around. if you remove the `?` after your first group it works.

Update: As @morja pointed out your solution is to move the first `.*?` into the optional src part.

Just for completeness: `/<script (?:.*?(src="(.*?)"))?.*?>(.*?)<\/script>/ig`

You can see it [here on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/lz67bDlSd5) (corrected my link also)

If you don't want to use the content of the first capturing group, then make it a non capturing group using `(?:)`

```
/<script (?:.*?(?:src="(.*?)"))?.*?>(.*?)<\/script>/ig
```

Then your wanted result is in $1 and $2.

Comment: I just want to capture the `src` attribute of a `script` tag, if it exists, no matter where it is in the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/<script (?:(?!src).)*(?:src="(.*?)")?.*?>(.*?)<\/script>/ig
```

See here: [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/oSzGwRe9KC)

As stema wrote, the `.*?` matches too much. With the negative lookahead `(?:(?!src).)*` you will match only until a `src` attribute.

But actually in this case you could also just move the `.*?` into the optional part:

```
/<script (?:.*?src="(.*?)")?.*?>(.*?)<\/script>/ig
```

See here: [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/S66ud2TR9L)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the html you are retrieving? Your code works fine in a simple example: [jsfiddle (warning: alert box)](http://jsfiddle.net/hP3a6/)

My first guess is that one of your script tags does not have a src meaning you are left with a single capture group (the script contents).

Comment: Interesting... if you put a `type="text/javascript"` in front of the `src` attribute, you'll see the problem.  It looks like it might not be the groups that are the problem but rather the way that non-greedy captures work.